# Does `conda env update` remove packages that aren't part of the environment file?

Tags: python, conda

The [documentation for `conda env update`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/env/conda-env-update.html) does not really answer this question: After executing the command, is the environment now the same as described in the `-f FILE` yaml file or does it just add non-existent packages and upgrade outdated packages, leaving manually installed packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `--prune` option of `conda env update` is what you are looking for:

```
conda env update -f file.yml --prune
```

The option is mentioned in the [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/commands/env/conda-env-update.html)

Edit: As @MarkLoyman mentions, it has issues since conda 4.4 https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7279

Comment: thanks, so... that means it doesn't. How to get the opposite? A diff of the current environment and the yaml file?

Comment: @DarenThomas Indeed besides a diff I don't know any way you can obtain the list of packages present in the env and not in the env.yml file.

Comment: `--prune` doesn't work as expected since conda 4.4: [github issue 7279](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7279)